# When I try to develop a proof of image patent platform, how to share the images with others and keep the safety of them?

Tags: contract-development, dapps, proof-of-authority

I'm trying to develop a proof of image patent platform, and it can save and share images (and possibly some other files), too. My idea is to save the SHA256 of images in the chain, and to save the file in a database. If someone wants to share an image which he owns，he can make a transaction with others to give them the SHA256 of the image. Whoever gets the SHA256 can get the image file from the database. (Of course the database is on the cloud server and others can not connect it without access.)

I want to know whether it is possible for several people to share the same SHA256 on the blockchain.  Does this meet the rules of the chaincode?

If not, how should I design the contracts?  Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hello YangYifei, welcome!  No need to apologize for asking a question.  This is what this place is for :)  I recommend editing your post to remove the last paragraph. Asking for recommendations of resources is considered off topic here (go to ethereum.org or Reddit instead) This link can help you stay on topic https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - You might also consider focusing your question on whether it is possible to have people share the same SHA256 on the blockchain, and if so how.  I would keep the other question "If not, how else could I design the contracts?" for later.

Comment: Oh sorry for ignoring it. I have changed it. Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you put on the Ethereum blockchain is publicly visible. As soon as anyone posts a transaction, everyone will be able to see it, and depending on how accessible the 'database' is, anyone could then see the image.

If you've hidden or put the image database behind some sort of private area, then why use the blockchain at all? Why not just pass around the link to the image (in your case the sha256) around behind that wall?

If the database is public, and the links to the images are posted on the chain, then everyone will be able to see the images.

Comment: Uh... As a matter of fact, I want to develop a proof of image patent. And I want to make a visualization of the images, too... So I think the first step is to solve the safety of these images files... I read some articles and they say the best way is saving files in the Cloud and saving hash in chain. So I want to save it in the database in Cloud. Can you give me some more advice? Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: The site ethos requires me to keep the discussion on Ethereum. Did you understand my answer concerning the public nature of the chain?  Other than that, I guess I could point you to IPFS as opposed to "the cloud".

Comment: I think I can use private key to encryption the image file. And if someone want to share his own image, he can use the private key to authorize it... But my mind is not very clear now. I think I need to have try. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I just published something about a very similar idea: https://medium.com/@tjayrush/zero-storage-data-publishing-on-ethereum-1e0610d846d

Comment: I have read it. And it give me a lot of help. Thank you a lot! I will have a try! :)